# WordNet Get Wordlist Of Lexicographer Files

Tags: python, wordnet

I want to use wordnet to get a list of food related nouns. So I searched the wordnet homepage and found a list of lexnames with associated file numbers [here](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/documentation/lexnames5wn).

On the webpage there is this row:

`13   noun.food   nouns denoting foods and drinks`

Where can I download the associated files and is there a way to get the list of "food nouns" with the help of the `wordnet` python library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where can I download the associated files

Download [the whole of Wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/download/current-version) (if you scroll down that page you'll see there is a section to get "WordNet 3.1 DATABASE FILES ONLY")

Look inside dict/dbfiles, and you'll see one of the files is noun.food, 269KB.  (It is fairly human-readable.)

> is there a way to get the list of "food nouns"

Search for the "food" synset, and then get all the direct and indirect hyponyms.